# How to show a dialog all by itself (without parent widget) in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, spyder

In the context of a parent class like a main window, it is easy to pop up a dialog like a message box:

```
QMessageBox.information(self, "Title", "Here is your informative message")
```

This pops up the message I want, with parent being `self`, the widget already open. But what if I want to show such a dialog in the middle of a Python program all by itself (say, to tell them their program has finished running, or whatever), without invoking a parent class?

I tried the following, and the dialog shows, but when I click OK my system hangs for a few seconds, no message is printed, and my Python kernel restarts (with no error message):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mess = QMessageBox()
mess.setText("Here is your message")
mess.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
returnValue = mess.exec_()
if returnValue == QMessageBox.Ok:
    print("Clicked OK!")
elif returnValue == QMessageBox.Cancel:
    print("Cancelled?!")
print("\n\nNow we are done")
```

When I click Cancel, it seems to work fine. I am not sure what Qt rules I am breaking here. I could just roll my own little popup using a `QWidget` I suppose.

I am in pyqt5/python 3.7 running in Spyder/iPython. When I run directly from the command line, it actually seems to work, so this could be an iPython or Spyder problem.

Comment: Could you explain me better, could you show an example of *Python program*, has *Python program* created a different QApplication from the one shown in your question?

Comment: This is the entire application right now and it exhibits the weird behavior. I am assuming zero other PyQt code, that this could be something a user uses and I just want to make them a popup dialog after, say, some lengthy analysis has finished (or whatever).

Comment: It seems to me that if you want help you should offer a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc ???  I did. The code block is a SSCCE that reproduces my problem, and shows exactly what I want to do, and I explained exactly the problem that happens when I run it.

Comment: It is that I have already executed it and I do not observe that problem, perhaps I have not executed it as you have done so I ask you for an MRE, an MRE is not necessarily code but it can be a set of specific steps: for example open spyder, press such a button, move such a thing, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc hmmm mabye b/c I'm using spyder/ipython, I edited to add this. So in general, you think the code looks ok and it works on your system?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this thread? https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2019-June/041884.html Btw, you can still call the static functions of QMessageBox even without a parent window, just use `None` for the first argument instead.

Comment: @musicamante that is really helpful I didn't know that was allowed! Maybe turn that into an answer?

Comment: @eric Do you mean that using the static function in that way you don't see the same behavior?

Comment: @musicamante good point it answers how to call  without a parent widget in a better way, but I do seem to get similar weird behavior and it hangs. This should be really simple, no? I just want a dialog to open and close without destroying my kernel. :)

Comment: @eric I'm not able to reproduce your problem on Linux with both PyQt 5.13 and 5.7.1, even with iPython, but I don't use Spyder, which *may* be partially responsible for it (but I'm just guessing).

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think this is going to be fixed in Spyder **4.1.0**, to be released in a couple of days. At least your example doesn't restart the kernel for me anymore on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code was only "broken" when using Spyder, and now works for newer versions of Spyder (versions 4.1+). So it wasn't a PyQt issue at all, ultimately, but an IDE interaction effect.

Answer (score 2):

Simply replacing `self` with `None` seems to display the QMessageBox in the middle of the screen.

```
QMessageBox.information(None, "Title", "Here is your informative message")
```